# Hannover theme, subsections in sidebar

Tags: beamer

I am preparing a presentation using Hannover theme. 
I am using `\usetheme[hideothersubsections, width = 2cm]{Hannover}`

The problem is that when I make some `\pause` commands, the subsection in which those are used appears as many times as `\pause` commands I have. That makes the sidebar to be highly redundant, see below.

[image]

What I would expect is to have the subsection name appearing only once, and, more than that, only the name of the subsection in which the slide apears to be shown. In fact, it seems that the option `hideothersubsections` is useless, there is no difference in the look of the output with or without it.

Comment: Are you using `\subsection` inside a `frame`? If so, then don't; otherwise, provide the code allowing us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks soo much Gonzalo. I was indeed using \subsection in one of my frames. I changed this - at first I was not that happy about beeing told where to en my subsections, but it works.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Seems you solved the problem. Is it possible to convert your comment to an answer to remove the question from the unanswered?

Answer (score 1):

Converting [@GonzaloMedina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268932/hannover-theme-subsections-in-sidebar#comment645505_268932)s comment into an CW-answer:

This happens if you use `\subsection` inside a frame. It should be placed outside.